# How do I setup a Amazon Elastic Network Interface so I can route a public IP to a server in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC setup with a public and private subnet.  I want to put my Windows Server 2012 email server in the private subnet, but use a ENI to give it a public IP.

Since my server is in the private subnet, I assume I need to create the ENI in the public subnet.  The only problem is that if I enable the ENI adapter, then I can no longer see other servers in my private subnet and if I disable it, I cannot see it from the public side.

How do I setup the gateway IPs and such so it will work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to put the server in a public subnet with an elastic IP.

There are mail sending limits in place on EC2 instances and when you request the limit removal (via https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) You'll be able to enter the Elastic IP to get whitelisted.

Comment: On this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#best-practices-for-configuring-network-interfaces  it shows a diagram and states that it is possible to create a dual homed setup where one ENI is in the public subnet and the other is in the private.  Just wondering how I achieve this in the manual network configuration for each NIC on the server.

Comment: You DO NOT have to do what Jason Floyd said... it's one option, but the response from "Developr" above is the cleaner approach.